# Antiderivative of $|\cos(x)|$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Is it possible to find a closed expression of the antiderivative of $|\cos(x)|$, i.e. express the antiderivative by combining/composing other elementary functions?

I have already found a related question, [How to find $\int|\cos x|\,dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/935261/579544) but it doesn't answer this question satisfactory.

Comment: Why isn't that satisfactory? There is a formula for the antiderivative of $|\cos(x)|$. What do you want more?

Comment: As I see it, the difficulty, which I regard as insurmountable, is that the correct formula for the anti-derivative necessarily involves the factor sign$(\cos x)$.  The difficulty is that this factor depends on whether $x$ is in the 1st or 4th quadrants, versus the 2nd or 3rd quadrants.  Therefore, there is no ready association (for example) between this factor and the factor sign($\sin x)$.  That is, this separate factor depends on whether $x$ is in the 1st or 2nd quadrants, versus the 3rd or 4th quadrants.

Comment: @LegNaiB, not sure to which formula you refer? The accepted answer to that question is wrong. And the other relevant one is a piece-wise defined function which works but is not one expression that can be used for all $x$.

Comment: $$
\int|\cos x| \, dx = \int_{0}^{x}|\cos t| \, dt+C \, .
$$

Comment: Let $t:=(x+\frac\pi2)\bmod\pi$ and $n=\dfrac{x-t}\pi$. Now the integral is $n$ times the integral over a full period plus the integral over $[-\frac\pi2,x]$.

Comment: @Joe maybe my question was too imprecise in that issue but I am looking for an expression other than the indefinite integral.

Comment: @Philipp: Okay. Note that an integral having a "closed form" is generally considered different to it being "expressible in terms of elementary functions". Closed forms often include special functions like $\operatorname{li}$ and $\operatorname{Si}$.

Comment: @Philipp okay, I haven't looked through the answers in detail, but why exactly is the accepted answer not correct? It seems correct and nobody said anything contradictory

Comment: @LegNaiB the proposed "antiderivative" is not continuous at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Hence, it can't be an antiderivative.

Comment: Using the accepted answer to your linked question, the function can also be written as cos(x)sgn(cos(x)).

Comment: Check [Christian Blatter's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/936461/612017) and definition in the presented graph.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find $\int|\cos x|\,dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935261/how-to-find-int-cos-x-dx)